# Backspace not erasing character, similar to BASH

Tags: c

I can parse input, traverse up and down in the history but my backspace does not work. Why is that?

```
void printPrompt(void)
{ // prints working directory prompt
    char cwd[256];
    getcwd(cwd, 255);
    printf("%s> ", cwd);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you press Backspace?

Comment: There's too much code. Could you try to narrow it down into simple specific test case?

Comment: This is a duplicate post, direct cut and paste from "Why is backspace here not working?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to print out a `DEL` (dec 127) when you should be sending a `BS` (dec 8). You'll also probably then want to send a space and another `BS` to clear out that character (`BS` just moves the cursor). So, when you get `buf[0] == 8`, print out `8`, `32`, `8`.

```
else if (buf[0] == 8)
{ // Backspace
    if (charsRead > 0)
    {
        line[charsRead - 1] = '\0';
        charsRead--;
        printf("%c%c%c", 8, 32, 8); // CHANGE HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The backspace is working.  The problem is the redisplay of the line after the backspace.   You should probably print a carriage return (\r) and then reprint the line including the prompt.

Edit:  I'm not certain that my suggestion is 100% portable across terminals either.  You may need to use something like curses to handle the portability issues.